# Google Sheets / COUNTIF value is X and date is TODAY

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a long list of dates in column C with a long list of names in column D.

I need  to count how many times a certain name is mentioned but only if the date next to it is today.

So if today's date is 16/11/2022, and I want to find the name "Peter", this formula should return "2".

| Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- |
| 16/11/2022 | Peter |
| 16/11/2022 | Peter |
| 17/11/2022 | Peter |

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=COUNTIFS(C:C; TODAY(); D:D; "Peter")
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(COUNTIFS(INT(C:C), TODAY(), D:D, "Peter"))
```

[image]

Comment: Hey boss, thank you so much as always. I tried but it wont work. I think it's because in column A, the date is not in DD/MM/YYYY format but it also includes the time, so it says for example 16/11/2022 09:58:37. Any ideas on how to fix that so the time will be ignored and only the date will be taken into consideration?