# Scheduling: Counting the number of times a name is present based on the current date

Tags: google-sheets, schedule, countif

I have a full year of individual dates listed chronologically from A3:A367. In B3:B367, I have names of staff members. This is a yearly schedule. I need to know the count of a each staff member's name based on the current date. Example below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wx1Mp.png)

I understand how to do a YTD count using this formula in a different tab, but need to know the count based on the current date:

=COUNTIF('Current Schedule'!B3:B367,A4)

Thank you,

Tried using the word TODAY in the formulas...

Comment: based on the provided info, there's just going to be a ***single instance of current date*** in the calendar list (A3:A367). lets say `kelly` is the person scheduled on current date (Column B). bit unclear on what are we counting here when you say `Counting the number of times a name is present based on the current date`?!

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear - lets say the current date is 3/13/23. How many times does Kelly's name come up before that? What is the formula to generate that number? The formula has to be live to the current day.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you familiar with `COUNTIFS`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Sheets / COUNTIF value is X and date is TODAY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74464578/google-sheets-countif-value-is-x-and-date-is-today)

Comment: I've not tried countifs and the link unforfunately doesn't answer my question. That counts a persons name based off of a single date. I don't have any single dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=countifs('Current Schedule'!A$3:A$367,"<="&today(),'Current Schedule'!B$3:B$367,A3)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=countifs(A3:A367,"<="&today(),B3:B367,filter(B3:B367,A3:A367=today()))
```

Comment: See my test file here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KFlfUIJz6m7VfyI4DkGSD46UMQwwDLF6/edit#gid=1240839318

Comment: I need the number of times a persons name exists on the first tab from the start of the year until the current date. I have the YTD formula already.

Comment: YTD stands for Year_to_date (*from the start of the calendar/fiscal year to the present/specified date*); yet you are counting the whole of the calendar year and marked it under YTD for some reason!

Comment: try this for `Mike` (and you can drag the formula down) `=countifs('Current Schedule'!A$3:A$367,"<="&today(),'Current Schedule'!B$3:B$367,A3)`

Comment: apologies. This is literally my first StackOverFlow question ever. I appreciate the patience.

Comment: OMG THAT WORKS! Thank you so much. Saved me hours. Thanks!